# when clicking on Edit-Button Data disappear

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

When i click on select button in button data fill on form with specific ID but i set form disabled i mean no field is editable  because i want  user to click on Edit button than Data in form is enabled and user can Edit. But when click on Edit Button its Clear all fields

Please Help me i am stuck

this is my Edit button Code

```
protected void btnEDIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_ID.Enabled = false;
    TextBoxPN.Enabled = true;
    TextBoxCP.Enabled = true;
    TextBoxCUR.Enabled = true;
    TextBoxMIN.Enabled = true;
    Catogary_drop.Enabled = true;
    Vnder_Drop.Enabled = true;
    Sattus_Drop.Enabled = true;
    TextBoxRMKS.Enabled = true;


    btnADD.Enabled = false;
    btnCLSE.Enabled = true;
    btnCNCL.Enabled = true;
    btnEDIT.Enabled = false;
    btnUPD.Enabled = true;

}
```

And this is my Gridiew Select Index code

```
protected void GridViewitem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow row = GridViewitem.SelectedRow;
     txt_ID.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
     TextBoxPN.Text=row.Cells[2].Text;
     TextBoxCP.Text=row.Cells[3].Text;
     TextBoxCUR.Text=row.Cells[4].Text;
     TextBoxMIN.Text=row.Cells[5].Text;
     Catogary_drop.Text = row.Cells[6].Text;
     Vnder_Drop.Text = row.Cells[7].Text;
     Sattus_Drop.Text = row.Cells[8].Text;
     TextBoxRMKS.Text=row.Cells[9].Text;

     txt_ID.Enabled = false;
     TextBoxPN.Enabled = false;
     TextBoxCP.Enabled = false;
     TextBoxCUR.Enabled = false;
     TextBoxMIN.Enabled = false;
     Catogary_drop.Enabled = false;
     Vnder_Drop.Enabled = false;
     Sattus_Drop.Enabled = false;
     TextBoxRMKS.Enabled = false;

     btnADD.Enabled = false;
     btnCLSE.Enabled = true;
     btnCNCL.Enabled = true;
     btnEDIT.Enabled = true;
     btnUPD.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**IsPostback** check in Page_Load event may help you. Or You need to disable the postback on your edit button click.